# How can I make Google Search Console display day before month?

Tags: google-search-console

In Google Search Console (previously known as Webmaster Tools), there are often charts like this one:

[image: Chart screenshot]

What I find very unusable are the dates at the bottom. I would much prefer them to be in British or Europen format, that is day/month/year, and not month/day/year. Or even better, year-month-day.

I have set my language to English (UK) but this doesn't seem to have made any difference. How can I configure Search Console to do this?

Comment: Urghhhh, US dates!  Confusing my life on a daily basis!

Comment: I have my search console set to swedish and I get the year-month-day formatting on my graphs [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/zGn45Zt.png).

Comment: @NatalieHedström : One more reason to learn Swedish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like you can't control this at present. I will send this feedback to the Search Console team - it might be a point to update as they roll out the new Search Analytics reports.